# How to Make Java MouseMotionListener update faster

Tags: java, swing, draw, frame-rate, mouselistener

I am currently making a simple drawing app using the MouseMotionListener mouseDragged method and I noticed that when I moved my mouse quickly across the frame, I think it is moved too fast for the listener to pick up on everything I crossed over. Is there some way to change how often the listener detects an event?
Here is a photo of what it looks like when I drag quickly:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7udm.png]

Comment: No you can't increase the frequency of the events. The solution is to draw a line between two consecutive points. See: [How to reduce the response time of MouseInputAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327350/131872) for a working example

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with Java or MouseMotion, and it would really only apply to your local machine, you can hack your USB polling rate (or get a gaming mouse with software that supports it out of the box) and might get more updates. The MouseMotion events fire due to messages the operating system sends to the application (java) and java 'rewrites' them into MouseMotion events for your application to handle. Your problem is the operating system, not Java. You can work around this by 'connecting the dots' as camickr said.