# JAVA: mouseDragged getX and getY raw data erratic

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I am trying to code a paint like program (for fun), but to challenge myself I tried to do it using setRGB method, but I see that when I move the mouse fast the behavior of the stroke gets erratic, do you know how to "soft" the data get from methods getX and getY? or why I am getting random points colored

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english. :)

[image: Stroke fast vs slow]

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

int canvasW;
int canvasH;
BufferedImage imgCanvas;
int X1;
int Y1;
int X0;
int Y0;
int sizeCanvas = 10;
int expCanvas = 2 * sizeCanvas - 1;

public Canvas(int width, int height) {
    canvasH = height;
    canvasW = width;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    CanvasImage(width, height);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public BufferedImage CanvasImage(int width, int height) {
    imgCanvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    return imgCanvas;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(imgCanvas, null, null);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

public void drawer() {
    int deltaX = abs(X1 - X0);
    int deltaY = abs(Y1 - Y0);
    double m;
    double b;

    if (deltaX >= deltaY) {

        if (deltaY == 0) {
            m = 0;
        } else {
            m = (X0 - X1) / (Y0 - Y1);
        }

        b = Y0 - m * X0;
        if (X1 > X0) {
            for (int i = X0; i <= X1; i++) {
                imgCanvas.setRGB(i, (int) (m * i + b), Color.BLACK.getRGB());
                System.out.println(i + " ; " + (int) (m * i + b));
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = X0; i >= X1; i--) {
                imgCanvas.setRGB(i, (int) (m * i + b), Color.BLACK.getRGB());
                System.out.println(i + " ; " + (int) (m * i + b));
            }
        }
    } else {

        if (deltaX == 0) {
            m = 0;
        } else {
            m = (Y0 - Y1) / (X0 - X1);
        }
        b = X0 - m * Y0;

        if (Y1 > Y0) {
            for (int i = Y0; i <= Y1; i++) {
                imgCanvas.setRGB((int) (m * i + b), i, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = Y0; i >= Y1; i--) {
                imgCanvas.setRGB((int) (m * i + b), i, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    X1 = e.getX();
    Y1 = e.getY();

    drawer();
    repaint();
    X0 = X1;
    Y0 = Y1;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    X0 = e.getX();
    Y0 = e.getY();
}
```

Comment: You can't rely on a MouseEvent for every pixel. You need to draw a line between two MouseEvents. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327201/swing-how-to-reduce-the-response-time-of-mouseinputadapter/65327350#65327350 for a working example.

Comment: Thank you @camickr !, any particular reason why this happens? I am wondering how the manage to do it for example in photoshop

Comment: *!, any particular reason why this happens?* - if you generated event for every pixel on fast movement, then the system would be bogged down responding to the events. *I am wondering how the manage to do it for example in photoshop* - with code like I gave you in the example