# How can I draw a circle that compounds your cursor movement?

Tags: java, geometry, awt, mouseevent, awtrobot

I am trying to draw a circle with my cursor while I am moving it. I know the circle wont be perfect but that does not really matter I just need the circle to compound on top of my organic cursor movements. I originally tried to do this with java's awt robot class but that ended up being futile because anytime I moved my mouse massive lines would extend infinitely far from where I made that movement. Here are two sets of code I tried (keep in mind I am calling these from a  nativeMousePress event so I am holding down the left click the whole time).

```
        int radius = 100;
        for (double i = 0; i < (2 * Math.PI) + Math.PI / 6; i = i + Math.PI / 6) {
            PointerInfo pointerA = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point a = pointerA.getLocation();
            int yStart = (int) a.getY();
            int xStart = (int) a.getX();
            robot.mouseMove((int) ((xStart) + (radius * Math.cos(i))), (int) ((yStart) + (radius * Math.sin(i))));
            robot.delay(68);
        }
```

Here is my another attempt I had. I also want to mention that I need the delay in between each stroke.

```
    robot.mouseMove(getX() + 40, getY() + 20);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() + 20, getY() + 40);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() - 20, getY() + 40);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() - 40, getY() + 20);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() - 40, getY() - 20);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() - 20, getY() - 40);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() + 20, getY() - 40);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(getX() + 40, getY() - 20);


public int getX() {
    PointerInfo pointerA = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point a = pointerA.getLocation();
    return (int) a.getX();
}

public int getY() {
    PointerInfo pointerA = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point a = pointerA.getLocation();
    return (int) a.getY();
}
```

Ok now here is the image that shows what happens when I barely move my mouse. This happens with both sets of code even though each set of code makes the circle slightly different.
[image]

Now to reiterate what I am trying to do I want to be able to move my mouse freely around the canvas while the code tries to make circles which should likely lead to a compounding effect. The issue is when I tried to use the robot class it completely bugs out and makes massive lines every which way if you attempt to move the mouse. I already asked other people about this and no one could figure out a solution to this so I am wondering if there is another class I can access that can do what I am looking for. Anyways here is a picture of what I assume it would look like if I moved my cursor to the right and if my circle code worked. (I already figured out how to do the loop effect)
[image]

Lastly I wanted to mention that I dont want a solution that provides code that can make the shape I showed above because thats not the point since I plan to do more complex things with this later. I just really need to know how to automate moving my cursor while having its movements compound with my active mouse movements.

Comment: You don't need a Robot. Keep an ArrayList of Point objects. Then the custom painting code simply draws lines between each set of points. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327201/swing-how-to-reduce-the-response-time-of-mouseinputadapter/65327350#65327350 for a working example of this approach. You can modify the code to manually add points to an ArrayList and you would use a Swing Timer to animate the adding of each point.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.awt.Robot` generates inputs events automatically. In your code, for one human input event, robot is generating 12 input events over 68x12 milliseconds. So while robot is still generating 12 events if human gives more input events then mouse pointer location will jump back and forth between robot inputs and human inputs. The problem is both robots and human are giving mouse coordinates at the same time.

---

1. one solution could be to ignore human events while robot is generating click events. But distinguishing between robot generated events and human generated events will be very hard task. And things will get complicated.
2. I think the easiest option will be to draw one circle for one human mouse drag input. Think it as circle/spring pattern brush. Like they have air brush in drawing tools.

   I know you don't want the code. But to convey my points better here is minimal code for the approach:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Test extends Frame implements MouseMotionListener {
    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    private double i, radius = 10;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void init() throws Exception {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBounds(50, 50, 500, 550);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        new Test().init();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        me.consume();

        //do this to avoid multiple circles drawing at the same time
        synchronized (lock) {
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            if (x1 == 0) x1 = x;
            if (y1 == 0) y1 = y;
            
            i=Math.PI+(Math.PI/6)*2;
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++, i +=(Math.PI / 6)) {
                x2 = (int) (x + (radius * Math.cos(i)));
                y2 = (int) (y + (radius * Math.sin(i)));
                paint(getGraphics());
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
                radius += 0.3;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150); //change delay to suite ease of use
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) { //reset
        synchronized(lock) {
            radius = 10;
            x1 = 0;
            y1 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:
[image: drawing]

Comment: Is there another way to modify the movement of a cursor besides from using a robot? Because I need to be able to move the cursor while its creating circles.

Comment: I tried using jnativehook since it can natively get my mouse's click and motion movements but as far as I know it can not modify my cursors location.

Comment: What you can do is make user draw guiding line first(start and end point).  Once they are done you start moving cursor with robot along that guiding line.  Taking user input while robot is moving will make cursor jump here and there.

Comment: Ok but is there really no way for java to move your cursor while you move it? I ask this because I know basic scripting languages like AutoHotKey can even do this so it just shocks me that Java cant.

Comment: Do you have auto hot key script for what you are trying to achieve? A minimum working script will give better understanding. Can you draw the spiral pattern in MS paint using the auto hotkey script?

Comment: No I have not gotten the circular motion to work but I did get moving in a straight line to work which is an improvement over java.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127393/using-java-to-run-a-autohotkey-script-to-move-cursor