# How can I draw a line between 2 points in Graphics in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, graphics, interface

I have this code, lista is an ArrayList of Points that i add to the list everytime the user of the interface drags the mouse. But when i do that i get an error: "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3"

```
for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            g.fillOval(lista.get(i).x,lista.get(i).y,radio*2,radio*2); 
        if(lista.size()>1){
            g.drawLine(lista.get(i-1).x,lista.get(i-1).y,lista.get(i-2).x,lista.get(i-2).y);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using "-1" and "-2" to alter the index values? This seems to imply you want to paint the points from the end of the array to the beginning, in which case your starting index would be the end of the array and you would decrement "i" for each iteration. Just paint from the beginning, in which case you should be using "i" and "i + 1" See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327201/swing-how-to-reduce-the-response-time-of-mouseinputadapter/65327350#65327350 for a complete working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first iteration through this loop, i-1 will be -1 (and i-2 will be -2) this is where you problem is

```
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            g.fillOval(lista.get(i).x,lista.get(i).y,radio*2,radio*2); 
        if(lista.size()>1){
            g.drawLine(lista.get(i-1).x,lista.get(i-1).y,lista.get(i-2).x,lista.get(i-2).y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to change `if(lista.size()>1)` to `if (i > 1)`?

Comment: Yes, I´ve fixed it by adding that too, size can be greater than 1 but when the method its called again, i starts at 0, thats why i needed i>0. `if(lista.size()>1 && i>0)`.

Comment: @Angel *thats why i needed...* - you don't need any any if statement. All you need is a properly coded for loop.