# I want to create a simple Paint in Java

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent

I want to modify the program to connect the series of dots that make up one stroke of a letter with a straight line so that words can be drawn but i don't really have a idea of how to do it so i want some references. I tried to draw them using drawLine but it's not what i really wanted.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZpB.png]

This is my code:

```
package tool;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Point {
    int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}

public class MyPaintApp extends JFrame {
    int x, y;
    Vector<Point> list = new Vector<>();

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    list.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Point p : list)
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 4, 4);
        }
    }

    public MyPaintApp() {
        setSize(600, 450);
        setLocation(400, 0);
        setTitle("My Paint");
        add(new MyPanel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Point {
    int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}

public class MyPaintApp extends JFrame {
    int x, y;
    Vector<Point> list = new Vector<>();
    Vector<Vector<Point>> list1 = new Vector<>();

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    list.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                Point p1 = list.get(i);
                Point p2 = list.get(i + 1);
                g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);  
            }
        }
    }

    public MyPaintApp() {
        setSize(600, 450);
        setLocation(400, 0);
        setTitle("My Paint");
        add(new MyPanel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm studying this in my University and i do understand the basics of Swing but i just have problem with connecting the dots here. @davidalayachew

Comment: I realize now that you were asking a wildly different question than what I had assumed. I am typing up an answer to your actual question now.

Comment: That said, the wording of the text is not very clear either. What you are really trying to say is that "I used the method `drawLine` to attempt to draw lines, but I only got a bunch of dots in the shape of a line instead of actual lines. How do I connect the dots?" I would encourage you to edit your question to say that instead.

Comment: @davidalayachew Wow, i appreciate it a lot. Yeah, as you said, I'm still a first year Uni student and I'm still not comfortable enough with Swing, specially with Paint Component but i have to finish my assignment for my professor so i really do need help.

Comment: @davidalayachew Ah, no no, this is because i edited to question. Actually i have another code that i wrote but because i feel like that one is even worse than the original so i edited my post.

Comment: np. One thing that would help -- in your screenshots, was the image with a bunch of dots created by the code snippet you pasted above? And if so, please also post the code for the one that created the lines. Or are you saying that you hand-drew that second screenshot?

Comment: Hmmmm, we may be talking past each other then. Please edit your question to include more detail about what you are looking for. Why didn't `drawLine` work for you?

Comment: Ah yeah, the image with a bunch of dots is created by the code snippet I pasted above. For the second screenshot, that's my goal. And it's my professor' picture of his finished code. @davidalayachew

Comment: Ok, then that is very easy to solve. You must do a call to `drawLine` connecting the current point in the `Vector` with the next point in the `Vector`. I would post a code example, but that would be giving you the entire answer. I thought your problem was much more complex.

Comment: @davidalayachew Ah yeah, i tried that: 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                Point p1 = list.get(i);
                Point p2 = list.get(i + 1);
                g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);  
   }
        }
    }
But the problem is after i did this, the lines are all connected so i cannot create another words.

Comment: @davidalayachew Also, the lines are too smooth so it didn't look like my professor's request so i didn't use it.

Comment: Ah, so it was as complicated as I originally thought. Ok, smooth lines are likely not a problem. But connected, "cursive-like" words probably are. In that case, we will have to use *some* of that complicated stuff I talked about and then deleted. Post your snippet into the original post, and I will write an answer.

Comment: @davidalayachew yeah, i just edited it.

Comment: Ok, ty. And finally, just to confirm, can you explain the MouseListener part of your code? It looks like you are creating dots, and then trying to connect them. Why draw dots in the first place? Why not start by drawing lines? Is that just what your professor wants you to do for this assignment? Seems a little backwards to me.

Comment: @davidalayachew Uhm, yeah, the original code was provided by my professor and i have to fix it so it can match the second screen-shot.

Comment: @davidalayachew Uhm, yeah, i can.

Comment: LOL, then you can swap out the Vector creation with drawLine. I don't know if your professor would be happy with that

Comment: Doing it that way would be 4 lines of code to solve this entire problem lol

Comment: If you want multiple distinct lines then you need a Vector of Vectors to contain the points for each line. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327350/131872 for a basic example.

Comment: @camickr Yes, you and I are saying the exact same thing. However, the OP can avoid the Vector entirely, unless their assignment requires them to save the points too.

Comment: Deleting my answer since it is no longer relevant. After all, we can just use drawLine and get the solution

Comment: If you are having trouble visualizing it, lmk

Comment: @Davidalayachew So you are saying that using drawLine would be a better solution for my problem? Then, is there a way to modify the lines too? Like to make them bigger or sth. Sorry, i just came to uni so i couldn't respond until now.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the example, i will try it that way.

Comment: No problem. Yes, that is exactly like what I am saying. I will write an answer anyways.

Comment: @davidalayachew Ohh, thanks. I will look at it after finishing my course.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Drag (multiple shapes)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private List<List<Point>> shapes = new ArrayList<>(8);
        private List<Point> currentShape;

        public MyPanel() {
            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    currentShape = new ArrayList<>(64);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    shapes.add(currentShape);
                    currentShape = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    currentShape.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            addMouseMotionListener(handler);
            addMouseListener(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            for (List<Point> shape : shapes) {
                paintShape(shape, g2d);
            }
            if (currentShape != null) {
                paintShape(currentShape, g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintShape(List<Point> shape, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Point from = null;
            for (Point p : shape) {
                Point to = p;
                if (from != null) {
                    g2d.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
                }
                from = to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Connected lines

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>(8);
        private Line2D nextLine;

        public MyPanel() {
            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (nextLine != null) {
                        lines.add(nextLine);
                    }
                    nextLine = new Line2D.Double(e.getPoint(), e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (nextLine == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    nextLine.setLine(nextLine.getP1(), e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            for (Line2D line : lines) {
                g2d.draw(line);
            }
            if (nextLine != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.draw(nextLine);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintShape(List<Point> shape, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Point from = null;
            for (Point p : shape) {
                Point to = p;
                if (from != null) {
                    g2d.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
                }
                from = to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Disconnected lines

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>(8);
        private Line2D nextLine;

        public MyPanel() {
            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (nextLine != null) {
                        lines.add(nextLine);
                        nextLine = null;
                    } else {
                        nextLine = new Line2D.Double(e.getPoint(), e.getPoint());
                    }
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (nextLine == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    nextLine.setLine(nextLine.getP1(), e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            for (Line2D line : lines) {
                g2d.draw(line);
            }
            if (nextLine != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.draw(nextLine);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintShape(List<Point> shape, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Point from = null;
            for (Point p : shape) {
                Point to = p;
                if (from != null) {
                    g2d.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
                }
                from = to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Some notes

- Don't use `Vector`, use `ArrayList`, you probably won't notice it, but `ArrayList` will be faster
- The Graphics 2D API already has a `Point` class, don't re-invent the wheel
- The "state" information the panel uses to paint the contents should be relative to it (or provide via some kind of model)
- `paintComponent` should be `protected`, there's no reason for anyone else to be calling it

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class MyPaintApp extends JFrame {
   Vector<Point> list = new Vector<>();
   Vector<Vector<Point>> list1 = new Vector<>();

   class MyPanel extends JPanel {
      public MyPanel() {
      
         final MouseAdapter mouseAdapter =
            new MouseAdapter() {
               public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                  repaint();
                  list.add(event.getPoint());
               }
               public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                  repaint();
               }
               public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                  if (list.isEmpty()){
                     return;
                  }
               
                  list1.add(list);
                  list = new Vector<>();
                  repaint();
               }
            }
            ;
      
         this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
         this.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
      }
   
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         for (final Vector<Point> listA : list1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listA.size() - 1; i++) {
               Point p1 = listA.get(i);
               Point p2 = listA.get(i + 1);
               g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("this-escape")
   public MyPaintApp() {
      setSize(600, 450);
      setLocation(400, 0);
      setTitle("My Paint");
      add(new MyPanel());
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      new MyPaintApp();
   
   }

}
```

In this case, we don't even create any of the dots that you did. All we did is grab the point from the event using `MouseEvent.getPoint()`, then add it to our `Vector`. I also changed your `MouseMotionAdapter` to just be a plain `MouseAdapter`. Doing so gives us the `mouseMoved`, which I just used to reset our `Vector` and start a new one. Have to run, so I can answer questions when I get back.

Comment: Hmm, it says something like the method add(Point) in the type Vector<Point> is not applicable for the arguments (java.awt.Point). And as a second thought, i think my professor will make us keep the class Point too i think.

Comment: Can you paste your first answer again? I want to look into it a little bit.

Comment: I have fixed my code like this and I think it's quite ok now but it still looks a bit different from the example, but i think this might be close what my prof requested so I just want to post to confirm a little bit:

Comment: Hello, sorry I missed your questions. Do you still have unresolved requests? As a fair warning, MadProgrammer is one of the experts on Swing, so their answer will by higher quaality than mine.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Point {
    int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}

public class MyPaintApp extends JFrame {
    int x, y;
    Vector<Point> list = new Vector<>();
    boolean isMousePressed = false;

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                    isMousePressed = true;
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    list.add(new Point(x, y));
                }
                
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                    isMousePressed = false;
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(isMousePressed) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    list.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                    }
                }
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(isMousePressed) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    list.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f)); 
            for (Point p : list)
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 4, 4);
        }
    }

    public MyPaintApp() {
        setSize(600, 450);
        setLocation(400, 0);
        setTitle("My Paint");
        add(new MyPanel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```